# Proper syntax for ansible symlink

Tags: nginx, vagrant, ansible

*What is the proper syntax for creating symlinks using ansible?*
I'm creating a Vagrant virtual environment and running ansible as my provisioner. Everything works fine up until I try to symlink to my site nginx configuration file from sites-enabled. Here is what I've tried.

```
- name: Create symlink to example.com
  file: 
    path: /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.com 
    dest: /etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com 
    state: link
  notify: nginx reload
```

When I do this I'm met with the following error.

> ERROR: Syntax Error while loading YAML script, /Users/username/project/ansible/roles/nginx/tasks/main.yml
>
> Note: The error may actually appear before this position: line 24, column 1
>
> - name: Symlink to example.dev.conf
>
> file: path=/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.dev.conf
>
> state=link
>
> ^ Ansible failed to complete successfully. Any error output should be visible above. 
>         Please fix these errors and try again.

I've also tried using `src=/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` instead of `path` but I can't seem to find a definitive example of this on the web.

Specs:

- OSX Mavericks
- vagrant 1.6.3
- VirtualBox 4.3
- nginx 1.6.0
- ansible 1.6.2
- ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 36, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/file_module.html):

> *src*, path of the file to link to (applies only to state=link). Will accept absolute, relative and nonexisting paths. Relative paths are not expanded.

You need to use `src` and `dest` when using `state=link`, not `path`. You also need to invert your source and destination, which appear to be the wrong way around (assuming that you really want to link to `sites-available` from `sites-enabled`) — `src` is the path to link to, `dest` is where to create the symlink.

```
- name: Create symlink to example.com
  file: src=/etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com dest=/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.com state=link
  notify: nginx reload
```